# mySQL, PHP: два AND после BETWEEN - что бы это значило?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть чужой (рабочий) код вида:

```
    $sql = "SELECT    
                `s`.`name1`  AS `name1`,
                `p`.`name2` AS `name2`, 
                COUNT(*) AS `name3`    
            FROM `table` `s`
                LEFT JOIN `results` `r`  ON `r`.`id` = `s`.`result`
                LEFT JOIN `products` `p` ON `s`.`product_id` = `p`.`id`
            WHERE
                `s`.`name4` BETWEEN '{$startdate}' AND '{$enddate}' AND 
                {$curReestr['sm_where']}
            GROUP BY 
                `s`.`name1`, `p`.`name2`";
```

Не уверен, что последнее AND предлагает проверку переменной на равенство единице. Если это все же так, то не понимаю как БД будет сравнивать выбранные строки с переменной, которая определена в скрипте. Каково здесь может быть назначение AND? И, если здесь проверка на истинность или равенство единице, то как здесь mySQL взаимодействует с PHP?

Comment: один AND относится к between, а второй - это просто AND - соединяем два условия.

Comment: mySQL не проверяет проверяет переменные PHP. Она вообще ничего не знает про РНР. Можешь вывести $sql на экран и убедиться, что никаких переменных в ней нет.

Comment: @Ипатьев, вот и я так думал/ю. но в условии-то стоит переменная PHP, в фигурных скобках смарти: AND 
                {$curReestr['sm_where']}

Comment: ну и каша. Смарти здесь вообще не при чем. ты $sql вывел?

Comment: @KoVadim, т.е. проверка переменной на единицу/истинность? тогда непонятно что может значить окончание запроса AND {$curReestr['sm_where']}, где переменная в фигурных скобках равна 1?

Comment: а там точно единица, а не какое то условие?

Comment: @KoVadim, удалось разобраться - при определенных условиях 1 может стать операцией сравнения. спасибо за участие